# Mongoid Relations 1..*

Tags: ruby, mongoid

Consider the following:

```
class Picture
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :data, :type => String
end

class Cat
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_one :picture, :autosave => true
  field :name, :type => String
end

class Dog
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_one :picture, :autosave => true
  field :name, :type => String
end
```

Now, is it possible to do the following:

```
dog = Dog.new
dog.picture = Picture.new
dog.save!
```

Without having to edit the Picture class to the following:

```
class Picture
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :cat
  belongs_to :dog
  field :data, :type => String
end
```

I don't need pictures to know about it's `Dog` or `Cat`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could do this if you put the `belongs_to :picture` in your dog and cat classes. The side of the relation that has `belongs_to` is the side that will store the foreign key. That would put a `picture_id` field in each of `Dog` and `Cat`, instead of having to store a `whatever_id` for each type of think you want to link on your `Picture` class.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not. You need to have `cat_id` or `dog_id` or some  polymorphic `obj_id` for all of them to store information about belonging of this picture.

Or how do you know wich Picture belongs to current Dog or Cat?

Comment: Something like `Dog.first.picture`

Comment: so `Dog` should belongs_to `Picture` then